# Return list of words from a list of lines with regexp

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm running the following code on a list of strings to return a list of its words:

```
words = [re.split('\\s+', line) for line in lines]
```

However, I end up getting something like:

```
[['import', 're', ''], ['', ''], ['def', 'word_count(filename):', ''], ...]
```

As opposed to the desired:

```
['import', 're', '', '', '', 'def', 'word_count(filename):', '', ...]
```

How can I unpack the lists `re.split('\\s+', line)` produces in the above list comprehension? Naïvely, I tried using `*` but that doesn't work.

(I'm looking for a simple and Pythonic way of doing; I was tempted to write a function but I'm sure the language accommodates for this issue.)

Comment: It's times like these when I miss Haskell's concatMap...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> lines = ["hello world", "second line", "third line"]
>>> words = chain(*[re.split(r'\s+', line) for line in lines])
```

This will give you an iterator that can be used for looping through all words:

```
>>> for word in words:
...    print(word)
... 
hello
world
second
line
third
line
```

Creating a list instead of an iterator is just a matter of wrapping the iterator in a `list` call:

```
>>> words = list(chain(*[re.split(r'\s+', line) for line in lines]))
```

Comment: Pretty awesome way of doing it, though I'm disappointed Python doesn't allow a less "cluttered" way of doing it. Cheers.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `chain.from_iterable` without unpacking the list.

Comment: Easier to reverse-denest the comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get a list of lists is because re.split() returns a list which then in 'appended' to the list comprehension output.

It's unclear why you are using that (or probably just a bad example) but if you can get the full content (all lines) as a string you can just do

```
words = re.split(r'\s+', lines)
```

if lines is the product of:

```
open('filename').readlines()
```

use

```
open('filename').read()
```

instead.

Comment: Using Python 3 man! No more readlines(), and everything's Unicode.

Comment: Also, `re.split` doesn't take a list argument (I already tried that).

Comment: @Kevin True; however, I'm using `list(file)`.

Comment: @Beau, looking at your example I couldn't think of anything else other than something coming from a file or file-like type. Hence reading it as a string (as stated above) would be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this:

```
words = []
for line in lines:
  words.extend(re.split('\\s+',line))
```

It's not nearly as elegant as a one-liner list comprehension, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this old question, and I think I have a better solution. Normally if you want to nest a list comprehension ("append" each list), you think backwards (un-for-loop-like). This is not what you want:

```
>>> import re
>>> lines = ["hello world", "second line", "third line"]
>>> [[word for word in re.split(r'\s+', line)] for line in lines]
[['hello', 'world'], ['second', 'line'], ['third', 'line']]
```

However if you want to "extend" instead of "append" the lists you're generating, just leave out the extra set of square brackets and reverse your for-loops (putting them back in the "right" order).

```
>>> [word for line in lines for word in re.split(r'\s+', line)]
['hello', 'world', 'second', 'line', 'third', 'line']
```

This seems like a more Pythonic solution to me since it is based in list-processing logic rather than some random-ass built-in function. Every programmer should know how to do this (especially ones trying to learn Lisp!)